# Tomcat does not uncompress war file?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I using `Tomcat 6` to deploy my servlet web application. when I copy the war file (`myapp.war`) into the webapp folder of Tomcat. Sometimes I notice that myapp.war was uncompress into folder named `myapp`, but sometimes it was not uncompressed. In both cases, it still worked fine when I assess my webapp from the browser.

Why sometimes Tomcat does not uncompress my war file?

Comment: What does your <Host> configuration look like in conf/server.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when I didn't have proper permissions set for 'myapp' directory. If you are running tomcat on linux, set up Tomcat as the owner of 'myapp' directory.